# php - How to add backgroud image in PDF using silverstripe-TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

am trying to add an image to the pdf which genrates but its not working properly.

```
 $this->Image('footer.jpg', 20, 720, 560, 100, 'JPG');
```

am trying to add this in PDFgenerator.php file but not working. image file and PDFgenerator.php are in the same folder.

```
  $this->SetFont('Times', '', 12, '', true); works fine.
```

Comment: I guess we need more code or information to help you. What exaclty is "not working properly"?

Comment: image is not adding to the pdf. but when i change the the font type as above it changes

Comment: so i guess it's a path problem, did you try a relative path (e.g. './footer.jpg' ) or an absolute path (e.g. '/path/to/footer.jpg') ?

Comment: yes i tried. but no result

Comment: I think the question has nothing to do with silverstripe ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of "Full Page Background" ;)
I think the case is margins, header, and footer settings:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_051.phps